# Is there a way to use EJB authentication data to connect to persistent storage?

Tags: oracle, authentication, ejb, weblogic, persistent

There are a few users which have (1) username, (2) password and (3) role attributes.

I want to use credentials of a user to authenticate and authorize for EJB service operations (WebLogic 12c App Server).

At the same time, i want to use those credentials for connection to persistence storage (Oracle 11g Database), cause my customer wants to restrict db object access depend on user role attribute.

Is there WebLogic or Oracle Database facilities to do so?

Is there any way to do so?

Very glad to see all your responses. Thank you.

Comment: You can look at JAAS, it might be helpful